# Passing JSON to a bash script

Tags: bash, escaping, quoting

I am passing JSON to a bash script. The JSON includes fixed (known) key names, and values that come from an environment variable.

For example:

```
binary --foo="{\"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ\" : \"$MHZ\"}"
```

Which results in the literal call:

```
binary --foo={"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ" : "1234"}
```

If `MHZ` was `1234` in the environment.

Look at all that ugly escaping. It gets more annoying as this argument gets longer. Is there some way I can write an argument like this, possibly containing more key pairs, without needing to do work for each `"` that needs to appear in the literal argument value?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ MHZ=1234
$ echo binary --foo='{"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ" : "'"$MHZ"'"}'
binary --foo={"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ" : "1234"}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just trade 1 escape character for each `"` in the key and value, to 0 in the key and 2 in the value? Seems like a wash.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a here-document:

```sh
var=$(cat <<EOF
{"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ" : "$MHZ"}
EOF
)
```

After which, `$var` contains the desired value:

```
$ echo "$var"
{"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ" : "1234"}
```

Or you could use jq:

```
$ jq -nc --arg v "$MHZ" '{"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ" : $v}'
{"CYCLE_TIMER_FORCE_MHZ":"1234"}
```